# Why won't my RV electric fridge turn on after recently replacing my power converter?

Tags: refrigerator

I recently replaced my power converter in my RV now my fridge doesn't turn on not even the light inside doesn't turn on. I reset the GFCI and checked my breaker everything is good. I unplugged the fridge from the socket and ran an extension cord for the outside post but nothing has changed.

Why won't it turn on?

Comment: Sounds like the power not getting to fridge, maybe a broken wire in the plug or a broken connection or fuse inside the fridge.  A muti-meter would be helpful to check connections.

Comment: What happened to the old power converter?  Any chance whatever took out the power converter took out the fridge too? Running it off an extension cord from outside seems conclusive.

Comment: Since this is a _question_ and answer site (as noted in the [tour] - well worth the 2 minutes), I rewrote this to actually ask a question. If this isn't the question you intended to ask, feel free to [edit] to actually ask your question.

Comment: I recently moved to a different RV spot and I couldn't find my power surge protector it was late at night the next day we didn't have power so I looked around and my converter smelled burned so I replaced it now my GFCI plug and fridge doesn't work. I reset my GFCI plug and replaced the breaker and fuses for it but nothing.

Comment: Well, first check that there is voltage at the outlet.  Then plug something else in and verify it works (like a lamp).  But if plugging your fridge in to a separate system doesn't help, then most likely the fridge shorted out & died, which caused the converter to burn out as a result.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment that sounds like an answer:

> Well, first check that there is voltage at the outlet. Then plug something else in and verify it works (like a lamp). But if plugging your fridge in to a separate system doesn't help, then most likely the fridge shorted out & died, which caused the converter to burn out as a result. –
> Carl Witthoft
> Apr 4 at 17:13

Answer (score 0):

An RV fridge usually requires 12 volts DC to run its control circuitry, plus propane gas and/or mains electricity to provide the heat energy that actually cools the fridge (ammonia absorption cycle cooling). It sounds like your testing has focused on the mains-voltage supply but overlooked the 12 volt DC side.

The recently-replaced converter should be providing 12 volts DC to run lights, water pump, house battery charging, etc. Are all of those functions working? Check the DC fuse panel, main fuses, and so on.

When the DC system is confirmed to be working normally, turn your attention to DC supply to the fridge. It may be powered through a fuse in the main DC panel, but it might instead be powered from elsewhere in the vehicle such as a high-power fuse panel near the house battery. You may have to go poking around behind the exterior service panel for the fridge to find its DC power supply wires and confirm whether correct voltage is available there.

After that's all done, if the controls for the fridge still don't power on, one would suspect the fridge may be damaged. Then you're looking at repair or replacement of a component or the entire fridge.

Comment: When I plug it into the extension cord I hear a clicking noise from the fridge every now and then. Is there a possible way that the relay went out?